# No such module (dependency) within Framework

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

*Please do not mark as duplicate (as regular no such module thread), I was not able to find a similar thread. Even tho I have researched for a while now.*

I have updated a forked Framework to Swift 3. This Framework had a dependency, that needed to be updated as well.

I was not able to link `:git =>` within the `podspec` file, that is why I have chosen to delete the dependency from the `podspec` file and implement both Frameworks within my `podfile`.

```
pod 'ASTextInputAccessoryView', :git => 'https://github.com/davidseek/ASTextInputAccessoryView.git'
pod 'ASPlaceholderTextView', :git => 'https://github.com/davidseek/ASPlaceholderTextView.git'
```

`ASPlaceholderTextView` is a dependency of `ASTextInputAccessoryView`.

Within my project I'm able to import `ASPlaceholderTextView`.

[image]

But within the Framework `ASTextInputAccessoryView`, `import ASPlaceholderTextView` throws missing module.

[image]

I have tried to add `ASPlaceholderTextView` within `ASTextInputAccessoryView` Target's General -> Linked Frameworks:

[image]

As well as `ASTextInputAccessoryView` Target's Build Phase ->

[image]

I have cleaned and restarted several times. What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had such issue earlier when I was trying to include a thrid party framework in my application. I found a work around and it worked for me as below:

Go to app target -> General settings -> Embedded Binaries and add your framework here.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: do i need to keep the setup i have provided in my question following your solution? because just adding your solution to my setup didnt helped. unfortunately

Comment: also i have cleaned and restarted.

Comment: Yes. Just keep the setup as it is and add the framework in embedded binaries section. Once you add the framework in here, I think it will automatically add one reference in Linked Binary with Libraries also. Remove one reference manually if there are two. Try it and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please try to go into your build settings and defining the "Framework Search Paths" to a folder which contains the frameworks?